# Pixel height and width in degrees

Tags: netcdf, vector-grid

I am planning to create a NetCDF file from a script (Github). My shapefile is in GCS_WGS_1984 (this is one of the required files for the script). Now, the script requires to define the cell/pixel height and width in degrees. Furthermore, my purpose is to create a grid pixel/cell equivalent to a 500 m by 500 m pixel/cell. I am also posting the lines (degree values don't represent 500 m) where it's asking to define these values for further reference. Moreover, the project area is located in the Pacific North West (US).

```
###Cell height and width in degree, Edit accordingly
cell_h=0.05
cell_w=0.05
```

**Update**
Based on Mr. Stimsons' comment I have updated my question so that it can make more sense:

How can I approximate geographic coordinates (WGS 84) to 500 m? That way I will be able to determine the pixel height and width and replace those values in the code with appropriate values approximating a 500 m by 500 m pixel in degree.

Comment: You're not going to get an exact figure of 500m as the cells distort and become trapezoidal when viewed in a projected coordinate system. 0.05 degrees is actually quite a large number https://www.usna.edu/Users/oceano/pguth/md_help/html/approx_equivalents.htm has a rough guide which indicates the cell ~5km. You need to decide if you want your product in geographic units approximating 500m or if you want your product in metres (pick a projected CRS) with cells precisely 500m.

Comment: 0.05 was mentioned by the author of the code as an example on Github. Yes, I want geographic coordinates units (WGS84) approximating 500m in degree. Based on that approximation I will then replace 0.05 with that value as cell height and width in degree. Thank you for your guidance on this!

Comment: One thing you can do is to use QGIS. Create a point layer using a projected CRS (e.g. UTM). Add a point in your area of interest. Buffer the point by 500m. Use the Measure Tool to measure from your point to the vertical perimeter of the buffer and set it to degrees. Do the same for the horizontal. This is quick and dirty and there are more exact methods.

Comment: The problem here is that, to maintain X spacing, the value has to change with each row, and the Pacific Northwest US is far enough from the Equator that you can't use the same Y as X. I built a global fishnet grid for analysis, and had to make the *area* of each cell a constant 25 sq KM by varying the height of each row, using a width chosen near 32N so a fixed multiple of cells would cover the globe *exactly*. The result was squat rectangles near the Equator and tall rectangles near the poles, all with 25 million square meters +/- 145 sq m at seven decimal places.

Comment: For rough approximation, I use 1 degree = 60 nautical miles (111120m), and use cosine(latitude) to adjust the ratio of dX to dY (~2y near 60N). So, shooting for round numbers, that's 0.0045 degrees longitude by 0.0090 degrees latitude (0.009,0.0045 in x,y)