# Fishnet cell size accuracy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, vector-grid

I have a raster of 500m resolution based on MODIS sinusoidal projection, so I first converted it to WGS84. In order to create a 500m fishnet of the WGS84 raster in ArcGIS, I first converted the raster to points. Then, in the Fishnet tool, I entered `0.005` as cell height and width value to approximate a 500m grid polygon based on the approximation that `0.01° = 1.11 km`. My area is in the Pacific North West in the US. Did I enter the correct(approximate) cell size value or is there a more accurate way to this?

Comment: As addressed in the comments to your previous question, you are off by 100% in the X dimension [Pixel height and width in degrees](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375387/pixel-height-and-width-in-degrees)

Comment: According to your last comment to that question, you mentioned a value of 0.009 for x, so should I enter 0.009 for cell width?